# Install LunarVim via bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to install Lunarvim via bash script with the command linked on github

> bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)

But it does not work `"Syntax error: "(" unexpected"`

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `bash --version`.

Comment: `<(...)` is bash-only syntax. It doesn't work if you're running it from `sh` -- even if you're using `sh` to _start_ bash it won't work, because the syntax needs to be recognized by the shell that's first processing it..

Comment: @Cyrus, I doubt output from `bash --version` matters -- if the OP is running this code in `sh`, the problem happens before `bash` is started.